# Why doesn't the four-gluon vertex give mass to gluons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, quantum-chromodynamics, bose-einstein-condensate, gluons

We have a four-gluon vertex and a gluon vacuum condensate. Why doesn't this provide us with gluon masses, as in the [NJL model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nambu%E2%80%93Jona-Lasinio_model) where the condensate gives rise to an effective mass term?

Comment: in the page of your link, they point out the lack of confinement with chiral condensates in the theory

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the NJL model you get rid of the gluon. They are considered to be frozen in the low energy limit where you are working because the mass is higher than the energy. Thus you are only working with quarks, and you consider interaction between quarks via effective coupling constants.

But in the standard model, gluons (seem to) acquire an *effective* mass because of confinement. That's why the range of the strong interaction is short.
If you compare with photons, they  have no electric charge and the range of the electromagnetic force is infinite.

Comment: Gluons are massless.
Short range of strong interaction is not due to them being massive.

Comment: The bare mass of the gluon is zero. But due to the interaction it is considered to be dressed. See for example Origin of Mass from Frank Wilczek.

Comment: Well, "gluons acquire a mass because they carry a color charge" is not correct. Then you can talk of glueballs, etc, if you wish.

Comment: @xi45: it is more subtle than that. In the infrared, the gluon propagator saturates (i.e. does not diverge) as the momentum goes to zero, implying that the gluons are effectively massive, as it has been shown in lattice simulations.

Comment: @Adam Even a photon can acquire an effective mass in some situations. However, fundamentally it is massless. I just find the way it is put ("gluons get mass because of color") misleading, esp. for students (we're not all experts here). A precision would be welcome, I think.

Comment: @JSFDude in the (pop) ref of Wilczek, unless I'm missing something, one of the main points of that essay is to argue that the proton's mass comes essentially from massless stuff.

Comment: @xi45: fundamentally does not mean much I think. If, in the spectral function, you find a resonance at a given energy, you call that the mass of the excitation. This has nothing to do with the bare mass, which is only easily related to the real mass in weakly coupled theories. (Concerning your photon analogy : in QCD you don't need an external medium to generate a mass, only pure QCD does the job. So your "fundamentally" does not really work.)

Comment: @Adam fair enough about the analogy.  Still, at the level of the "fundamental" Lagrangian, gluons are massless and remain so to all order in perturbation theory. However, I agree, non-perturbative effect seem to show that gluons aquire a *not-directly-measurable* mass (Cornwall'82 + review by Aguilar-Papavassiliou'06). Not sure how to interpret this effective mass, and what's the theoretical status: if you have a good ref, please let me know. Thx.

Comment: @xi45: Well, at least it is measurable in "numerical experiments", i.e. lattice simulations (where we can get rid off the fermions). Unfortunately, I'm a dilettante, and I mostly follow the work of colleagues. But a very interesting approach, which starts from a "massive" QCD, is able to reproduce most, if not all, lattice results can be found in arxiv:1105.2475. They even can justify the presence of this mass from a certain form of gauge fixing. Worth to be read, in my opinion, but that's totally biased ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @JSFdude, in the NJL model, gluons are no more: they are replaced by the effective 4-fermion couplings.

That said, *ab initio* QCD calculations DO indicate that gluons could acquire non-zero mass. A [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04110) claims:

> Preliminary variational calculations[31–33] had shown that PT
>   might actually work at low energy and give reasonable results at the lowest orders of approximation if the expansion point is changed and the expansion is taken around a
>   massive gluon propagator. Regardless of the accuracy of
>   the zeroth order gluon propagator, provided that it has
>   a mass scale, the higher-order terms become small, suggesting that the failure of PT might be a consequence of
>   the bad choice of expanding around the usual mass-less
>   gluon propagator of the high energy theory. On the other
>   hand, the even earlier remarkable discovery of Tissier and
>   Wschebor[44, 45], that PT is viable if a gluon mass is
>   added by hand to the Lagrangian, suggested that the best
>   expansion point might actually be the simple free massive
>   gluon which emerges by just adding a gluon mass term
>   to the quadratic part of the Lagrangian and subtracting it again from the interaction, thus leaving the total
>   action unchanged.

where PT stands for perturbation theory.

Of course, the rigorous proof of "The mass of the least massive particle of the force field predicted by the theory is strictly positive" is still [pending with a prize of US\$1,000,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap). In comparison, a Lamborghini can start anywhere from \$200,000 to \$500,000. So I am not particularly enthusiastic in telling ya the proof here at PSE.